# How to detect a file has been uploaded in the server and then trigger a function in PHP without CRON

Tags: php, automation

I have created a web application in PHP with an option for admin to upload a CSV file and submit the form and it will update/create new records in the database.

Now we have developed a system that will generate CSV file in the server every time when there is an update. Now the task is to detect if there is a new CSV file has been generated and trigger the form submit function and update the database, so everything will be automated.

I am already aware of using CRON jobs but I want to run my update script instantly and do not want CRON to run for every minutes or second.

I want to know if there is any way to detect the generated file, kind of event listener (RabbitMQ?) or something that will be triggered whenever a new file comes up in the server (LAMP Based).

Please give me some idea, how can I achieve this. CRON can do it job but it is not preferred for me.

Thanks in advance
Sanny

Comment: _“Now we have developed a system that will generate CSV file in the server every time when there is an update.”_ - define “generate”, that could mean a lot of things.

Comment: Why don't you just call that function when the generation is done?

Comment: What @Elanochecer said ;) Also: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview

Comment: @04FS Sorry if I was not clear on my words...I mean that there is a different application say app2 which runs on a different server and when someone makes any changes on app2 it creates a CSV file with all the changes and remotely drops the file in our app1 server. My question was related to app1.

Comment: @Elanochecer if you read my above comment, you can understand why I can not just call the function when file is generated.